# "There are stopped jobs." when exiting bash

Tags: macos, bash

When I'm in the terminal (either iTerm or Terminal.app) and have jobs running in the background, then typing `exit` or `logout` gives me:

```
There are stopped jobs.
```

which is fine and expected. The problem is that if I run `exit` or `logout` again (and repeatedly), I get the same thing.

```
isbadawi@astaire:~$ exit
logout
There are stopped jobs.
isbadawi@astaire:~$ exit
logout
There are stopped jobs.
isbadawi@astaire:~$ exit
logout
There are stopped jobs.
isbadawi@astaire:~$ exit
logout
There are stopped jobs.
isbadawi@astaire:~$ exit
logout
There are stopped jobs.
isbadawi@astaire:~$ exit
logout
There are stopped jobs.
isbadawi@astaire:~$ exit
logout
There are stopped jobs.
```

I've used bash on linux, and the behavior there was for the second invocation of `exit` or `logout` to go ahead and terminate the stopped jobs. Instead, I have to do this manually. Why is the behavior different, and is there a way to make it the same?

Comment: I can't reproduce it in a 10.9 VM, so check your configuration files. You could also try to install a newer version of bash by for example running `brew install bash;echo /usr/local/bin/bash|sudo tee -a /etc/shells;chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`.

Comment: @LaurieRanta Upgrading bash (to 4.3.11 from the system 3.2.51) seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 6):

If you have jobs that are stopped (with CTRL-z) or happened to be in the background but are stopped waiting for input, you can see what's there with the 'jobs' command.

If you only have a job, then a 'fg' will bring it to the front for you to interact with it or kill with a 'CTRL-c'. If you have multiple jobs, you can bring individual or specific ones with 'fg '.

Comment: I know about job control (this is what I was referring to by "do this manually"). I am asking why bash seems to behave differently on OS X and Linux in this instance.